# HTML Page looks different when generated using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning to construct HTML/Web pages using JS.
How do i make my JS produce the same results as plain HTML in the below case?
Please help.

When i use the below HTML

```
<div id="TopAlert" class="TopAlert_Parent">
    <div id="TopAlert_Container" class="TopAlert_Container">
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the below result

[Correct results by plain HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K4H7.png)

When I use the below HTML

```
<div id="TopAlert" class="TopAlert_Parent">
</div>
```

With the below JS code

```
var topAlert = document.getElementById("TopAlert");
var topAlertContainer = document.createElement("div");

topAlertCount++; //Global variable

topAlertContainer.id = "TopAlert_Container"+topAlertCount;
topAlertContainer.style = "TopAlert_Container";
topAlert.appendChild(topAlertContainer);
```

I get the below result

[Incorrect generation by JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBVT0.png)

Below is my CSS

```
.TopAlert_Parent 
{

  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.TopAlert_Container
{
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Comment: `topAlertContainer.style = "TopAlert_Container";` — your code assigns the string to the `style` instead of the `className` property.

Comment: Also important, when do you call your javascript? It's possible you're trying to get an element the DOM doesn't see yet.

Comment: Thanks Pointy  I will update this and confirm back. Closed my devices and checking this post from my mobile. Will check as soon as I open my machine tomorrow. Thanks to you I believe I will sleep well tonight.

Comment: Phaelxz. I do this inside an event handler method. Received through websocket. I am sure it is triggered because, earlier I tried to set a simple inline html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were setting the `style` when you meant to be setting a `class` - and you can access the `class` property through `classList`, using `add()`

```js
topAlertCount = 0;

var topAlert = document.getElementById("TopAlert");
var topAlertContainer = document.createElement("div");

topAlertCount++; //Global variable

topAlertContainer.id = "TopAlert_Container" + topAlertCount;
topAlertContainer.classList.add("TopAlert_Container");
topAlert.appendChild(topAlertContainer);
```

```css
.TopAlert_Parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.TopAlert_Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div id="TopAlert" class="TopAlert_Parent">
</div>
```

Comment: This question has been answered by Pointy. Not sure how to mark this as answered.

Comment: I thought we answered it at about the same time and both answers are correct. Pointy uses className, I use classList.add(). Same diff